# Get time in 1ms increments

Tags: assembly, x86, clock

The x86 interrupt 0x1A seems to give the computer's clock time, but it can only give accurate time to within 55ms (AH=0). Is there any way to get smaller increments (and maybe a bit more "normal") than that, like maybe 1ms? I'm trying to make my own toy OS, so i can't use anything i can't write myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're making your own OS, you don't have to keep the timer period. It is possible to reprogram the PIT to trigger INT 8 (IRQ 0) more often. See [here](http://wiki.osdev.org/Programmable_Interval_Timer).

On newer computers you can also make use of the [High Precision Event Timer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Precision_Event_Timer).

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`rdtsc`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter) (read timestamp counter) instruction on x86 to get the 64-bit CPU timestamp into `edx:eax`. The implementation of this instruction depends on your processor, but it either increments once per clock or at a constant rate. Because of this, the time resolution also varies, but it should be better than 1ms.

There are some caveats to using `rdtsc`:

1. The timestamp counter is not necessarily in sync across CPU cores. This can be an issue in hyper-threaded and multi-core CPUs.
2. The counter doesn't necessarily increment at a constant rate. It can be affected by throttling or power-saving features of the processor.
3. Hibernation can cause the counter to reset.

Since you're writing your own OS, you might not need to worry about some of these issues.